# which client is talking?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have this simple server that 5 clients can connect to. Now the problem is how do I decide who is doing the talking at the moment?
It works for one client as it reads and sends using the same **i**. When there are 2 clients connected I'd like to send some type of unique id associated to the client that sent that message so the next time the message is sent the id should be the same as for the precious message.

small snippet of the server code where the connecting, sending and receiving is done.

```
while (true)
    {
    this->readingSockets = this->openSockets;
    this->socketBind = select(getdtablesize(), &this->readingSockets, NULL, NULL, (struct timeval *)NULL);
    if (FD_ISSET(sD, &this->readingSockets)) 
        {
            cD = accept(sD, (struct sockaddr *)&this->clientAdr,(socklen_t*) &this->sCadr);
            FD_SET(cD, &this->openSockets);
            continue; 
        }

for (int i=0; i<getdtablesize(); i++)
        if (i != sD && FD_ISSET(i, &this->readingSockets)) 
            {
                this->socketBind = read(i, this->buf, sizeof(buf));
                g1.cast(buf,id);//where i'd like to send that unique id
                if (this->socketBind == 0)
                {
                    FD_CLR(i, &this->openSockets);
                    close(i);
                }
                else 
                {
                    send(i,g1.getA(),g1.getSize(),0);
                    g1.setMsg(c);
                }
            }
    }
```

best regards.

Comment: wizard client is listening...

Comment: Are you sure your loop is correct? Are you not mixing loop counters with file descriptors?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, you have to get into the Halloween spirit!

Comment: @j_random_hacker nice one.
I am resisting the temptation to edit the title :P

Comment: @j_random_hacker that's one on me :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm assuming it is because it works for a single client.

Comment: @ogward: That's not a good reason to assume that it's correct, and in this case I really rather suspect that it is not. Rationalise about your code using analysis and logic, instead of assumptions with minimal sample sizes!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Whilst I appreciate the lolfactor, Stack Overflow is here for programming questions, not banter and commentary.

Answer (score 2):

You know that each of the five clients has its own connection on its own file descriptor (because you have accepted each connection separately), so you can analyze which client you are talking to by keeping track of the file descriptor you are working with.  For the identity of the client, you can look up the peer name with `getpeername()` which takes a socket file descriptor and the address structure.

The only time this could get messy, as I see it, is if the socket is established by one process and that process then forks and multiple processes end up using that socket.

Comment: ok... But when I read about getpeername() it says that it returns 0 if successful otherwise -1, I don't understand how that could help me identifying the client. Could you maybe show me some code?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'identifying the client'. The `getpeername()` function tells you the IP address of the process on the other end (but that's about all). If you need to know which program it is (it could be one of five different executables), and there is no guarantee that the process will be local (it could be running on another machine on the other side of the world), then you need a protocol such that the clients identify themselves to you. Of course, any Python script can send similar identification, so you should not authorize actions based solely on what the client says.

Comment: I was pretty unclear in my description. This is only going to be used for localhost. I'd like whenever a client connects an id is assigned to him(or something similar) so whenever he sends a message i can use that id and send it to a small game I've made. The id is only to distinguish the clients.

Comment: Use the file descriptor of the socket; it is a small non-negative integer that's unique while the client is connected.  When a client disconnects, you'll end up closing the file descriptor of the socket, and you can notify the game engine that the relevant client has left the game (before it is reused by a new connection).  Also, how are you going to ensure that the clients are only making connections from the local host?  By default, unless you've got a firewall in place, the sockets open for listening can be used by any process, local or remote.

Answer (score 1):

Create a struct of some sort:

```
struct GameClient
{
    int socket;
    char ip_address[30];
    int user_id;
    //etc
};
```

Maintain a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) of these connections:

```
std::map<int, GameClient> current_clients;
```

When you are reading from socket `sock_fd`, just get the info:

```
 GameClient* current_client = &current_clients[sock_fd];
```

When the client disconnects:

```
current_clients.erase(sock_fd);
```